# Бесконечная музыка на фоне в Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Необходимо реализовать бесконечную музыку на фоне. Ниже приведу фрагмент кода отвечающий за проигрывание музыки. Пожалуйста помогите исправить. На данный момент музыка проигрывается ровно на столько времени сколько занимает сама музыка. Есть ли способ сделать музыку бесконечной на протяжении всего времени пока приложение открыто? Спасибо.

```
self.music = SoundLoader.load('bg_music.mp3')
self.music.play()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из документации [kivy.core.audio](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.audio.html)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

class BGMusic(App):
    def build(self):
        self.play_music()
        return Label(text="BGMusic")
    def play_music(self):
        sound_loader = SoundLoader.load("music.mp3")
        sound_loader.loop = True
        if sound_loader:
            sound_loader.play()

def main():
    BGMusic().run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Loop петля или повторение.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но это не помогает. Ошибка ниже. 
load() got an unexpected keyword argument 'loop'

Comment: А если просто True вторым аргументом?

Comment: Тоже не получается. Теперь ошибка такая:
TypeError: load() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Может этот класс использовать kivy.core.audio.Sound ?

Comment: Можете подсказать как именно? Я импортировал Sound. Но теперь self.music.play() отказывается работать с использованием Sound вместо SoundLoader

Comment: Сейчас я у себя попробую воспроизвести проблему

Comment: loop свойство класса SoundLoader

Comment: Спасибо! Это помогло

Comment: Вы можете нажать стрелку вверх и галочку, это будет кстати.

Comment: Нажал на стрелку верх и галочку но увы пишет что голоса от участников с репутацией меньше 15 не учитываются. Очень жаль, но Вы мне очень помогли! Огромное спасибо! Выручили.